# Conditional Rendering in a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-native

I have to check weather the user is available, if so the background style is set. I can simply do this via PHP with a if statement, although how would this be done with react?

What I have so far:

```
<a className={classes} onClick={this.toggleDialog} { theUser.get('isAvailable') == 1 && style={{backgroundColor: "rgba(39, 174, 96, .15)"}} }  > 

{theUser.get('first_name')}

</a>
```

Comment: You'd wrap the tag in a conditional, if you mean you want to render the `<a>` iff the user is present. It's not clear that's what you want. This is pretty basic ReactJS stuff; you might want to brush up on how it works. It's all up in the docs and whatnot: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: I want to Render it all, although if the user is available I want to change the background color. - I know its basics, I've never done react before

Comment: You can try with `... onClick={this.toggleDialog} style={theUser.get('isAvailable') === 1 ? {backgroundColor: "rgba(39, 174, 96, .15)"} : {}} >`

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp ahhhh ternary completely forgot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Using ternary operator for inline styling:**

```
<a style={ theUser.get('isAvailable') == 1 ? { backgroundColor: "rgba(39, 174, 96, .15)" } : {} } />
```

**It's an option to use class names conditionally**, because it's much cleaner: (there's already a great library, [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)):

```
const classes = classNames({
  'available': theUser.get('isAvailable') == 1,
  'italics': true, // Will add `italics` className
  'bold': false, // Won't add `bold` className
})

<a className={classes} />
```

Answer (score -1):

There’s more than one way to use conditional expressions in React:

If/Else

Prevent rendering with null

Element variables

Ternary operator

Short-circuit operator (&& )

Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)

Subcomponents

High Order Components (HOCs)

If you are new to react I highly recommend to read the following:
https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e